# How to redirect output from the NASM command line assembler in C#

Tags: c#, ide, nasm

## Brief Summary

I am creating a lightweight IDE for NASM development in C# (I know kind of an irony). Kinda of like Notepad++ but simpler but with features that make it more than source editor. Since Notepad++ is really just a fancy source editor. I have already implemented features like Project creation (using a project format similar to how Visual Studio organizes projects). Project extension .nasmproj. I am also in the works of hosting it in an open-source place (Codeplex). Although the program is far from finish, and definitely cannot be used in a production environment without proper protection and equipment. In addition, I am working alone with it at this moment, more like a spare time project since I just finished my last Summer final taking Calculus I.

## Problem

Right now I am facing a problem, I can build the project but no output from NASM is being fed into the IDE. I have succesfully built a project, and I was able to produce object files. I even tried producing a syntax error to see if I finally see something come up but none and I check the bin folder of the test project I created and I see no object file creating. So definitely NASM is doing its magic. Is it because NASM doesn't want me to see its output. Is there a solution? Any advice would be great. Here is the code which I think is giving Trouble.

## Things to Note

- I have already checked if events have been invoked. An yes they have but they return empty strings
- I have also checked error data and same effect.

## Code

```
    public static bool Build(string arguments,  out Process nasmP)
    {
        try
        {

            ProcessStartInfo nasm = new ProcessStartInfo("nasm", arguments);
            nasm.CreateNoWindow = true;
            nasm.RedirectStandardError = true;
            nasm.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            nasm.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            nasm.UseShellExecute = false;                
            nasmP = new Process();
            nasmP.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            nasmP.StartInfo = nasm;
            bool predicate = nasmP.Start();
            nasmP.BeginOutputReadLine();

            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            nasmP = null;
            return false;
        }
    }
    //Hasn't been tested nor used
    public static bool Clean(string binPath)
    {
        if (binPath == null || !Directory.Exists(binPath))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Either path is null or it does not exist!");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryInfo binInfo = new DirectoryInfo(binPath);
                FileInfo[] filesInfo = binInfo.GetFiles();
                for (int index = 0; index < filesInfo.Length; index++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        filesInfo[index].Delete();
                        filesInfo[index] = null;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                GC.Collect();
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
                    using (BuildDialog dlg = new BuildDialog(currentSolution))
                    {
                        DialogResult result = dlg.ShowDialog();
                        dlg.onOutputRecieved += new BuildDialog.OnOutputRecievedHandler(delegate(Process _sender, string output)
                        {
                            if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                            {
                                outputWindow.Invoke(new InvokeDelegate(delegate(string o)
                                {
                                    Console.WriteLine("Data:" + o);
                                    outputWindow.Text = o;
                                }), output);
                            }
                        });

                    }
```

## Edits

- I have tried doing synchronously instead of asynchronously but still the same result (and empty string "" is returned) actually by debugging the stream is already at the end. So looks like nothing has been written into the stream.

This is what I tried:

```
            string readToEnd = nasmP.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            nasmP.WaitForExit();
            Console.WriteLine(readToEnd);
```

And another interesting thing I have tried was I copied the arguments from the debugger and pasted it in the command line shell and I can see NASM compiling and giving the error that I wanted to see all along. So definitely not a NASM problem. Could it be a problem with my code or the .Net framework.

Here is a nice snapshot of the shell window (although not technically proof; this is what the output should look like in my IDE):

[image: Output that is suppose to show up]

Alan made a very good point, check the sub processes or threads. Is sub process and thread synonymous? But here is the problem. Almost all the properties except a select few and output/error streams are throwing an invalid operation. Here is the debugger information as an image (I wish Visual Studio would allow you to copy the entire information in click):

[image: Debugger Information]

Comment: Daniel, for troubleshooting purposes you could try a synchronous alternative to see if that's where the problem comes from. Instead of BeginOutputReadLine() you could do something like "string output = nasmP.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd(); nasmP.WaitForExit(); Console.WriteLine(output);". Does this display any messages?

Comment: @Alan same result, I do not think it is a matter of async or sync. But thanks for the troubleshooting tip. Maybe NASM doesn't allow me to recieve output. Maybe I need a NASM developer opinion? But I have no Idea because it should technically work.

Comment: I see. The next thing I'd check is whether NASM launches a child process for compilation and it's the child process that actually generates the output on the standalone console, not the parent. This would explain why the output stream is not written to.

Comment: @Alan okay makes sense, I never thought about it like that okay!  Good point...

Comment: @Alan from the looks of the debugger the NASM process doesn't have any threads. In addition, every property from the process is throwing an exception. From the looks of the debugger. I will post an image of the debugger output.

Comment: Actually, thread and child process are different concepts (think of the latter as a program launching another program, similarly to what you are doing here). Using Task Manager you should be able to at least see if NASM spawned another process while running (an even better tool would be MS Process Explorer by Mark Russinovich; this one displays entire process trees, making it clear which process launched which).

Comment: @Alan thanks I actually tried MS Process Explorer but NASM assembles to fast for me to pause and actually view which sub processes it is looking into. Can you give me some tips on how to capture the nasm.exe. In addition, I have found some executable(s) relative to the nasm.exe. But I am unsure if these are being run. Thanks for the advice, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Hm, I doubt SO likes such lengthy comment threads, but I guess this is the last one from me today :) ProcExp can actually highlight differences (new processes and process exits) in the process tree, and you can configure the difference highlight duration in the Options menu. Set it to something pretty high, and you'll see what NASM did process-wise a long time after it exited. Hope this is not a red herring all in all :)

Comment: @Alan Sorry about the lengthy discussion. StackOverflow is starting to get bothered too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I finally was able to do it. I just found this [control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9621/ShellControl-A-console-emulation-control) that redirect output from a process and I just looked at the source code of it and got what I needed to do. Here is the the modified code:

```
public static bool Build(string command, out StringBuilder buildOutput)
        {
            try
            {
                buildOutput = new StringBuilder();
                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + " nasm " + command;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
                string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                p.WaitForExit();
                if (output.Length != 0)
                    buildOutput.Append(output);
                else if (error.Length != 0)
                    buildOutput.Append(error);
                else
                    buildOutput.Append("\n");
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                buildOutput = null;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Here is how the output is formatted like:

[image: The IDE With Output]

I also wanted to thank Alan for helping me debug my code, although he didn't physically had my code. But he really was helpful and I thank him for it.

Comment: Great news, and you're welcome:) So it's probably reading to the end of the redirected error channel that made the difference (plus, input redirection is really unnecessary with the arguments in place).